# I need to find an alternative way to replace specific values in my array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array and I need to take every '100' value and replace it with '200'. I was able to make it work using .where by itself but when I add it to my code it stops working.

This is what I used:

```
A= np.where(A== 100, 200, A)
```

Comment: you have to provide more detail , a piece of code that it can be reproduced and also include the error message

Comment: `A[A==100] = 200` maybe.

Comment: We can't help you with a that little information.  "It stops working" doesn't tell us anything.  Was there an error?  Full traceback.  Wrong values?  Was there something different abou the `A` - shape, dtype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only works if A is [100,100,100,100,100]

will not work if you have multiple columns.

If multiple columns, use pandas please.

Comment: Do I need to mask in this case?

Comment: I don't follow.  `np.where` should work just fine on a 2d array.  Why doesn't it work with multiplle columns?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).